# What happens in the Cramer-Rao bound if the quantum Fisher information is zero?

Tags: mathematics, quantum-fisher-information, quantum-metrology

The famous [Cramer-Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) is $$\Delta\theta\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt {F[\rho,H]}}$$
But what happens if the denominator vanishes, i.e., $F[\rho,H]=0$ ($F[\rho,H]$ here stands for the quantum fisher information in the unitary process)? For example, $F[\rho,H]$ can be zero in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4368) below eq$(26)$.

Comment: Well, it could only mean that variance of the unknown parameter $\theta$ is infinite.

Comment: But what does infinite variance mean, I mean, the physical meaning instead of the mathematical meaning?

Comment: I think you need to explain what is $\theta$, physically. The question, as it is currently formulated, is a formal mathematical question IMO.

Comment: infinite variance means that that you cannot estimate the parameter $\theta$ from measuring the state $\rho=\rho(\theta)$ with the measurement corresponding to $H$. Vanishing Fisher information in this context means that the state effectively does not depend on the parameter $\theta$ (hence why $\theta$ cannot be estimated from the state)